# How to show RefreshIndicator intially while waiting data from backend API?

Tags: flutter

So, I have this "Notifications" screen that displays notifications for the user. When navigating to this screen, it's going to be blank, since the notifications are being loaded live from a backend API.

Here's some code to illustrate the problem:

```
class _MyItemsPageState extends State<MyItemsPage> {
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
      new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  List<MyItem> _items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Nothing is displaying on screen initially, since the items are loaded from API on startup.
    // Preferably in this state, the refresh indicator would be shown while the items load.
    // It's not currently possible in this place, since it seems that the Widget hasn't been built yet.

    _refreshIndicatorKey.currentState.show(); // currentState null at this time, so the app crashes.
    _loadItems();
  }

  // (unrelated code removed)

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new RefreshIndicator(
        key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
        onRefresh: _loadItems,
        child: new ListView(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
          children: _buildItemWidgets(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that the **_refreshIndicator.currentState** is null when the **initState()** function is called, since the Widget hasn't been built yet.

What is the proper place of calling **show()** on the RefreshIndicator in this case?

Comment: As it turns out, putting the `_refreshIndicator.currentState.show()` inside my `_loadItems()` function did the trick.

So something like:

`Future _loadItems() async {
    _refreshIndicatorKey.currentState?.show();
    var items = await getItems();

    setState(() {
      _items = items;
    });
  }`

Not sure if it's the "most recommended" way, but at least that works ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  I'd still appreciate knowing if this is the preferred way!

Comment: You can self-answer your own question. Would you be up for answering formally below?

Answer (score 14):

I think the best option is to schedule the `_refreshIndicatorKey.currentState.show()` using the https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html  that way when the widget finishes the build is safe to make a call the show() method, and not depend on a fixed amount of time in the Future.

Here the example:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){  _refreshIndicatorKey.currentState?.show(); } );
  }
```

But, definitely, I do think that the widget itself can have an extra param to allow do that out the box.

Comment: Should definitely be a separate parameter in the widget.

Comment: I found that sometimes `_refreshIndicatorKey.currentState` ended up being null still. I switched to @mnemonic23's solution with the Future.delayed and that works more reliably. Still a horrible hack, though -- there must be a better way...

Comment: This solution works but I wonder if it will guarantee that the `currentState` is not null in all cases...

Answer (score 7):

As it turns out, putting the `_refreshIndicator.currentState.show()` inside my `_loadItems()` function did the trick. So something like:

```
Future _loadItems() async { 
    _refreshIndicatorKey.currentState?.show(); 
    var items = await getItems();

    setState(() { 
        _items = items; 
    });
}
```

Then I called the `_loadItems()` function like usual in the `initState()` method, but removed the `_refreshIndicatorKey.currentState.show()` line from there.

I think **this only works because of some possible race condition** due to the `async` nature of the loadItems function, and feel like there should be some other solution related to the lifecycle of the widget state.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I tried your way, but it was loading the items twice. it seems that calling `currentState.show()` was triggering the onRefresh callback. My solution was to just let `show()` make the call to onRefresh, which actually loaded the data.

Answer (score 3):

Solution suggested by **Iiro Krankka** didn't work for me, but He is right about race condition. So I tried to add Future.delayed on initState, and it did the trick. This seems ugly, but you know, it just works.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200)).then((_) {
    _refreshIndicatorKey.currentState?.show();
  });
}
```

**Update**

Basically `.show()` will trigger `onRefresh` of RefreshIndicator. So, actually by calling `.show()` inside `_loadItems` will trigger `_loadItems` twice. We don't want that. So I move `.show()` into `initState` and now we good, it just called once.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a package ([declarative_refresh_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/declarative_refresh_indicator)) that provides a declarative API for `RefreshIndicator`, similar to the `Switch` and `Checkbox` widgets.

Unlike other solutions, it can also allow the indicator to be shown initially without executing the refresh callback, allowing data to be requested in other places.

Here's an example that loads upon widget initialisation:

```dart
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  var _loading = false;
  
  void _load() async {
    setState(() => _loading = true);
    await _getData();
    if (mounted) setState(() => _loading = false);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _load();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DeclarativeRefreshIndicator(
      refreshing: _loading,
      onRefresh: _load,
      child: /* a scrollable widget */,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work with **CupertinoActivityIndicator**.

I ended up adding this to my CustomScrollView list of slivers just above the SliverList, and included an animated container that checks if loading from my provider. Works nice, smooth, no issues.

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                width: checkingForNewData || _images.isEmpty ? 70 : 0,
                height: checkingForNewData || _images.isEmpty ? 70 : 0,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
                curve: Curves.ease,
                child: Visibility(
                  visible: checkingForNewData || _images.isEmpty,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 50,
                    child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                      radius: 12,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```